# How to determine the recurrence relation described by the efficiency of this code

Tags: algorithm, recurrence, coding-efficiency

I´m new to algorithm analysis. I found this code online

```
boolean p (int s, int t, int n){
    if (n == 1) {
        if e(s, t) 
            return true;
        else
            return false;
    }
    else {
        for(i = 1; i <= n; i++) {
            if (p(s, i, n/2) and p(i, t, n/2))
                return true;
        }
    }
    return false;    
}
```

How can I determine the recurrence relation described by the efficiency of this code?

Supposing that the function `e(i, j)` returns a boolean and takes O(1)

Comment: O(1) is not "order(1)". It means in the worst case, it does a constant number of operations.

Answer (score 1):

To find out the recurrence relation in terms of **n**, consider the following code fragment.

```
for(i=1;i<=n;i++) 
{
    if (p(s,i,n/2) and p(i,t,n/2))
        return true;
}
```

We can see that the loop gets executed **n** times.
Notice that the loop is independent of the parameters **s** and **t**.

During each execution, this loop calls the function `p()` twice with parameter **n/2**.

Also notice that the other operations, including the function `e(i,j)` only takes constant time.

Thus the recurrence relation of the problem is `T(n) = 2n T(n/2) + O(1)`.